# Laravel Queue Chaining

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, chaining

How do I pass the data from one job in a chain to another?

```
XJob::withchain([
            new YJob()
            new ZJob(),
            new AJon(),
        ])->dispatch();
```

I want to pass $x from XJob to YJob and pass $y to ZJob and $x, $z to AJob().

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to the first job via the dispatch method. So your code should look like:

```
XJob::withchain([
    new YJob($y)
    new ZJob($z),
    new AJon($a),
])->dispatch($x);
```

Comment: I want to pass response of one job to another. $x is response of XJob and I want to pass it to YJon($x);

Comment: Have you figured this out? I am trying to do the same thing. I need to pass the result of job1 to job2 in the same chain. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Async Jobs cannot return data.
Where should they return it to.

You can but the Business Logic into separate Classes, and call methods from there, and put everything in a single Job. That would make more sense probably.

```
class A {
  public static method run() {
    return do_something_a();
  }
}

class B {
  public static method run($a) {
    // return do something with $a
  }
}
```

And now put this in a Job

```
class MyJobClass implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $a = A::run();
        $b = B::run($a);
    }
}
```